# sync-request with post parameter not working

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, post

I have to make synchronous request from nodjs app. I have found the sync-request https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request for making sync-request. But when I use below code I am getting some error on return data.

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: rpi_id in <b>get_data.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
```

Below is nodjs code.

```
var data_id ="data_1";
var url = "https://example.com/get_data.php";
  var request = require('sync-request');
  var res = request('POST', url, {
    json: {
    'rpi_id': data_id,
  },
    
  });

  // var data = JSON.parse(res.getBody('utf8'));
   console.log(res.getBody('utf8'))
```

and php code.

```
<?php

$data = $_POST;
$rpi_id = $data['rpi_id'];

$res=array('Response'=>'OK','Data'=>$rpi_id);
echo json_encode($res);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res.getBody().toString()
```

https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/shownodejs_cmd.asp?filename=demo_met_buffer_tostring

buffer to String ......

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you explain your answer to help everyone out?

Comment: we just do a stringa conversion in the buffer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you start using es2017 and use async/await. Http requests are normally asynchronous due to their nature of fetching external ressources, thus you can await the response of an asynchronous call.

Example:

```js
const got = require('got');
const url = "https://example.com/get_data.php";
const data_id = "data_1";

const execRequest = async (url, body) => {
    return got.post(url, {
        json: body,
        responseType: 'json'
    }
}

const result = await execRequest(url, {'rpi_id': data_id});

console.log(result.data); //contains your response
```

Here you can read/learn more about [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) and [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in how you're decoding the request in PHP side. [The PHP's `$_POST` has only `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` content-type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), not your JSON as `application/json` content-type.

To get the JSON object in PHP you should do the following:

```php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$data = json_decode($json);
$rpi_id = $data['rpi_id'];
```